# Cling: Getting started with device search

Tags: upnp, remote-control, smart-tv, android-cling

I'm new to UPnP development and recently started to use [Cling](http://4thline.org/projects/cling/) to develop a UPnP client in Java.

To me the Cling documentation is insufficient. Especially it's lacking of basic examples, such as discovering UPnP devices via IP address.

The search for all available devices is shown in an example:

```
UpnpService upnpService = new UpnpServiceImpl();
upnpService.getControlPoint().search(new STAllHeader());
```

However, this search is very slow compared to other UPnP applications, such as my remote TV control app on Android.

This leads me to three questions:

1. Can you point at good tutorials, that show how to use Cling to remote control TVs?
2. Is there a way to speed this search up? Or is there an alternative type of search that achieves the same results in less time?
3. How can I search for a device via its IP address directly?